# How to add props to a grouped array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an array of lets say:

```
const myArray: Array<any> = [
  {
    prop1: 66,
    prop2: 'something1',
    prop3: 0,
  },
  {
    prop1: 66,
    prop2: 'something2',
    prop3: 0,
  },
  {
    prop1: 66,
    prop2: 'something3',
    prop3: 0,
  },
  {
    prop1: 66,
    prop2: 'something4',
    prop3: 0,
  },
  {
    prop1: 66,
    prop2: 'something5',
    prop3: 0,
  },
  {
    prop1: 66,
    prop2: 'something6',
    prop3: 0,
  },
  {
    prop1: 66,
    prop2: 'something7',
    prop3: 0,
  },
  {
    prop1: 66,
    prop2: 'something8',
    prop3: 0,
  },
  {
    prop1: 66,
    prop2: 'something9',
    prop3: 0,
  },
];
```

I came to a scenario where I wanted to group my data so the array above would become an array tha contains 3 arrays and each array contains 3 items. I googled and found a solution for this problem via the following function:

```
export const MakeChunkArray = (array: Array<any>, number: number, prop?: any) => {
  if (!array.length) {
    return [];
  }

  if (prop)
    return array
      .sort((a, b) => a[prop] - b[prop])
      .slice(0, ((array.length + number - 1) / number) | 0)
      .map((c, i) => array.slice(number * i, number * i + number));

  return array
    .slice(0, ((array.length + number - 1) / number) | 0)
    .map((c, i) => array.slice(number * i, number * i + number));
};
```

I could call the above:

```
const myGroupedArray = MakeChunkArray(myArray, 3);
```

This would give me ONE array that contains THREE arrays, like this:

```
const groupArray: Array<any> = [
  [
    {
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something1',
      prop3: 0,
    },
    {
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something1',
      prop3: 0,
    },
    {
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something1',
      prop3: 0,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something2',
      prop3: 0,
    },
    {
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something2',
      prop3: 0,
    },
    {
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something2',
      prop3: 0,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something3',
      prop3: 0,
    },
    {
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something3',
      prop3: 0,
    },
    {
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something3',
      prop3: 0,
    },
  ],
];
```

What I would like to do which I thus far can not figure out is add a prop to the gropped arrays:
So that every child within a child array gets a position indexer:

```
const groupArray: Array<any> = [
  [
     {
      position: 1,
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something1',
      prop3: 0,
    },
    {
      position: 1,
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something1',
      prop3: 0,
    },
    {
      position: 1,
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something1',
      prop3: 0,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
     position: 2,
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something2',
      prop3: 0,
    },
    {
      position: 2,
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something2',
      prop3: 0,
    },
    {
      position: 2,
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something2',
      prop3: 0,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      position: 3,
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something3',
      prop3: 0,
    },
    {
      position: 3,
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something3',
      prop3: 0,
    },
    {
      position: 3,
      prop1: 66,
      prop2: 'something3',
      prop3: 0,
    },
  ],
];
```

please note the `position` prop.

What do I need to add to my `MakeChunkArray` function to make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code just a bit to not repeat so much code and be easier to read, I'm sure it could still be more improved but thats basically it for a starter

```
export const MakeChunkArray = (
      array: Array<any>,
      number: number,
      prop?: any,
    ) => {
      if (!array.length) {
        return [];
      }
    
      const sliceArray = array =>
        array
          .slice(0, ((array.length + number - 1) / number) | 0)
          .map((c, i) => array.slice(number * i, number * i + number));
          
    
      const sortedByProp = array.sort((a, b) => a[prop] - b[prop]);
    
      return sliceArray(prop ? sortedByProp : array).map((arr, i) => arr.map(childObj => ({ ...childObj, position: i })));
    };
```